# Why does setting leading and trailing anchor does not work but width does?

Tags: ios

I can't figure out why setting leading and trailing anchor to a view does not work, but when I set width it does work.
I have a `UIStackView` inside a `UIScrollView`, this is how I set my `UIScrollView`:

```
private func setupScrollView() {
    addSubview(scrollView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backButton.bottomAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    ])
}
```

and this is how I set my `UIStackView`:

```
        private func setupTextfieldsStack() {
        scrollView.addSubview(textfieldsStack)
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.35
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textfieldsStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            textfieldsStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            textfieldsStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            textfieldsStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)
        ])
    }
```

For some reason, the `UIStackView` only takes about half of the screen, but, when changing `scrollView.leading` to `self.leading` and for the `trailing` as well, that does work, and the `UIStackView` gets stretched to fit almost the full width of the screen.
Setting the width to be 0.95 of the UIScreen bounds also works.

So, my question is, why when I use `self` it does work but `scrollView` does not?
I do call `setupScrollView` before `setupTextfieldsStack` and the `scrollView` renders correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When setting up constraints between a scroll view and its subviews, these constraints will, by default, be used to calculate the `contentSize` of the scroll view (i.e. to define the scrolling behavior), but does *not* place any constraint the size of the subview.

In [Technical Note TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2154/_index.html), they say:

> In general, Auto Layout considers the top, left, bottom, and right edges of a view to be the visible edges. That is, if you pin a view to the left edge of its superview, you’re really pinning it to the minimum x-value of the superview’s bounds. Changing the bounds origin of the superview does not change the position of the view.
>
> The `UIScrollView` class scrolls its content by changing the origin of its bounds. To make this work with Auto Layout, the top, left, bottom, and right edges within a scroll view now mean the edges of its content view.
>
> The constraints on the subviews of the scroll view must result in a size to fill, which is then interpreted as the content size of the scroll view. (This should not be confused with the `intrinsicContentSize` method used for Auto Layout.) To size the scroll view’s frame with Auto Layout, constraints must either be explicit regarding the width and height of the scroll view, or the edges of the scroll view must be tied to views outside of its subtree.
>
> Note that you can make a subview of the scroll view appear to float (not scroll) over the other scrolling content by creating constraints between the view and a view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as the scroll view’s superview.

That advice of solving this problem by adding constraints between the scroll view’s subviews and “a view outside the scroll view’s subtree” is a little out of date. In iOS 9, they introduced some layout guides that solve this problem, namely the [`contentLayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2865870-contentlayoutguide) and the [`frameLayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2865772-framelayoutguide). The former is used to define the scroll view’s `contentSize` (i.e. the scrolling behavior) and the latter is used to define the subview’s `frame` relative to that of the scroll view.

So, when adding subviews to a scroll view, you generally want to set all four top, bottom, leading, and trailing constraints to the scroll view’s `contentLayoutGuide` (so it scrolls correctly). Then define the leading and trailing anchors to the scroll view’s `frameLayoutGuide` (to ensure the subview has the appropriate width):

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    textfieldsStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
    textfieldsStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
    textfieldsStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8),
    textfieldsStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),

    textfieldsStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
    textfieldsStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much.